# SCSS - Is there any way to override inline styling without the usage of !important?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to override an inline styling in my SCSS file.
However, as we are using AMP, I'm not allowed to use !important.

Now I'm wondering if there is any way to override inline styling without the usage of !important?

Comment: No, there is no other way to overrule it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to overrule it without !important. This is because inline styles always take priority, unless overruled by !important.

If you must remove the inline styling and don't have the ability to update the HTML, you can remove the inline styling with JavaScript using [.removeAttribute("style")](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp).

You can read more on CSS Precedence [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)